# PHP is not printing array's column

Tags: php

Well, there is a pretty strange behaviour in my code.

I'm executing an SQL query inside a `foreach` loop like so

```
...
$sql = $database->prepare("SELECT CODE FROM tel WHERE CODE = ?");
$sql->execute([$e->code]);
    
$CODE = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($CODE);
...
```

The output of this is the screenshot below

[image]

if I change my code to this

```
$sql = $database->prepare("SELECT CODE FROM tel WHERE CODE = ?");
$sql->execute([$e->code]);
    
$CODE = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($CODE["CODE"]);
```

This mess appears on my screen

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Why is this in array brackets `$sql->execute([$e->code]);`?

Comment: Could it be that a lot of your queries, in the loop, do not return a valid result? They return `false`. You don't see this because `print_r(false);` outputs nothing.

Comment: When there is a code, it outputs it, when there is no code, then **obviously** it errors out

Comment: @mardubbles perhaps that's how it should be written?

Comment: OK folks, I got it. The $e->code is a unique id of another table. When the $e->code is not found in the table tel, then there is no row to return so I got the error as above. Really stupid me, I took for granted that all the $e->codes would exist in my tel array